# Multiple domains with wildcard certificates on single Apache2 virtual host

Tags: https, certificate, apache2, apache2.4

Is there any good way to use multiple wildcard certificates with single Apache 2 `VirtualHost`?

I have one IP based VirtualHost which is hosting websites from multiple domains. Each domain has wildcard certificate and I have been trying a way to make as compact as possible configuration file for this kind of situation.

At the moment, I have one VirtualHost for each main domain, but the configuration file is getting quite large when I am adding more domains.

Comment: Can you post one vhost configuration? is it always the same "layout" per vhost? If yes, did you ever think about Ansible or so to manage the mass of configurations?

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the general SSL Certificate installation guide for Apache2 Virtual Host, there is no other simple option available.

Make sure to enable the SNI.

Comment: That's what I have already done. I am looking for a solution to detect the certificate file to use automatically instead of creating separate configurations for each. Could not find any way myself and wanted to see if someone else knows a way to do it.

Answer (score -2):

If you have one IP, you can define multiple VirtualHosts on it. Every VirtualHost has its own certificate and ServerName and that works well together with SNI.

The „problem“ is, that there is no configuration option for this kind of problem. This is a „limitation“ of mod_ssl configuration options. You could use additional domains in the certificate, in that case you have one vhost per DocRoot.

If the size of the configuration is your problem, then it would be a good advice to use a configuration directory (with include) and put one file per domain or virtualhost in it. That’s the way, distributions are managing vhosts. In this case you can easily switch or copy to the configuration you need. In my case (900 domains) this works very well. I‘ve also added variables on the beginning of a domain vhost file that is used inside the configuration for DocRoot, Logfile, ServerName and ServerAliases.

Comment: This is what I am doing now, as I have said in the first post. No improvement in any way.

Comment: So - thats what I want to say. There is no other way, except you write your own mod_ssl.

Comment: The „problem“ is, that there is no configuration option for this kind of problem. If the size of the configuration is your problem, then it would be a good advice to use a configuration directory (with include) and put one file per domain or virtualhost in it. That’s the way, distributions are managing vhosts. In this case you can easily switch or copy to the configuration you need. In my case (900 domains) this works very well. I‘ve also added variables on the beginning of a domain vhost file that is used inside the configuration for DocRoot, Logfile, ServerName and ServerAliases.